# Google Analytics for Android tracking id protection

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am integrating my Android application with Google Analytics and was wondering what kind of security measures should be taken to avoid my analytics data being deliberately polluted by bad people. Sure, GA data is not production-critical, and there are (hopefully) not too many people running around who do such things just for fun, but still - within reason, I'd like to apply whatever preemptive measures there are. 
Right now the only thing that comes to mind is that I should avoid the tracking id falling into bad hands.

Google search results I found only talk about:

- protecting the tracking id for webpages - not so much talk about how to do the same for Android applications
- setting up a GA filter to include traffic data for my own webpage only - again, this is just for webpages...

When submitting hits from my app, there seem to be two ways for the data to reach the GA servers:

1. If Google Play Services is not installed, `putHit` runs and fires an HTTPS query with the hit data. If log level is set to debug, I can see this happening, and the data in the ADB logs, along with the tracking id.
2. If GPS is installed, that will take care of dispatching presumably also over HTTPS.

So this leads me to think that the best I can do on the application front is to make sure log level is above debug (which is a good idea regardless) and to encrypt the tracking id to at least make it difficult to extract from the APK.
On the GA front, I have not found anything similar to the webpages-filtering solution.
Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 2):

After you login into: Google Analytics
Under Admin > View > Filter > New Filter > Custom - you could possibly choose to filter by Application Id.

Application Id i believe is the package name you set in your manifest file.

Again this is not fool-proof: 
Anyone else can setup the same Application Id too, but it will require more effort.

Google Analytics - shud hv provided a better way to solve this.